# Issue accepting input of type char

Tags: c++

I am trying out a simple program. This works fine when the input is Y or y, or n or N. However if i enter the input as YY or yy, it behaves differently. Can you explain why? The same does not happen when the input is NN or nn.- I am new to programming and so pls help me out

```
void main()
{
    char ch = 'y';
    int choice;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number :";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "do you want to continue :";
        cin >> ch;
    } while ((ch == 'y') || (ch == 'Y'));
}
```

Comment: When you enter `nn`, it quits because of the first `n`, so it doesn’t matter what you type after that. When you type `yy`, it reads the first `y` as a yes, and then tries to read the second `y` as a number, which fails.

Comment: This question is definitely asked many times

Answer (score 1):

Your input: `YY`

`cin>>choice;` tries to read an integer but it fails. The error flags are set which renders `cin` unusable.

It is already in a fail state and you try to read a character. It ignores you. This keeps happening continuously over and over again because you have initialized `ch` to `Y` (and `cin` did not modify `ch` because it is in a fail state) which will keep the loop running forever.

If you want to get `cin` working again after an error, you need to clear the error bits using `cin.clear()`. Note that `cin.clear()` resets the error bits but does not shift the stream pointer ahead. This means that you are still at the first `Y` after using `cin.clear()`.

If you add `cin.clear()` after `cin>>choice;`, the `cin` errors will be reset (if there were any) and will let `cin` continue. As said earlier, the stream pointer will still be pointing to the first character and hence `cin>>ch;` will end up reading the first character. This process repeats and `cin>>choice;` will fail again and `cin>>ch;` will end up reading the last `Y`. Now `cin>>choice` will try to read something but it realizes that it has reached end of input (aka end of file; EOF). This will once again set the error bits. You clear the error bits and let `cin>>ch;` read something but this fails too because you have already reached the end. As `ch` previously had 'Y' or 'y' (because you are in the current iteration which implies that the condition was satisfied), it will continue to remain as it is. You end up with an infinite loop again.

The fix is to set `ch` to 'N' inside your loop at the top so that the loop breaks in case of an error. Optionally, you can ignore the erroneous input (character for `cin>>choice;`) using `cin.ignore();` right after using `cin.clear()`.

```
void main(){
    char ch;
    int choice;
    do{
        ch='n'; //assume no unless told
        cout<<"Enter a number :";
        cin.clear();
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<"do you want to continue :";
        cin>>ch;
   }while((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'));
}
```